# Invalid image height when converting a specific (seemingly valid) GIF to an mp4

Tags: ffmpeg

I've come across a weird GIF file on the internet that ffmpeg doesn't seem to like. Try running the following commands:

```
curl http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/34300000/Klaus-The-Originals-klaus-34349255-120-113.gif > input.gif
ffmpeg -y -i input.gif -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" output.mp4
```

I get the following output with ffmpeg version 3.4.6 and 4.1.3:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.3-0ubuntu1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, gif, from 'a.gif':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: gif, bgra, 120x113, 5 fps, 5 tbr, 100 tbn, 100 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (gif (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x5613f5420c80] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x5613f5420c80] profile High, level 1.0
[libx264 @ 0x5613f5420c80] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=5 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'o.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 120x112, q=-1--1, 5 fps, 10240 tbn, 5 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
[gif @ 0x5613f540edc0] Invalid image height.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[gif @ 0x5613f540edc0] Invalid image height.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[gif @ 0x5613f540edc0] Invalid image height.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[gif @ 0x5613f540edc0] Invalid image height.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[gif @ 0x5613f540edc0] Invalid image height.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[gif @ 0x5613f540edc0] Invalid image height.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[gif @ 0x5613f540edc0] Invalid image height.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[gif @ 0x5613f540edc0] Invalid image height.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[gif @ 0x5613f540edc0] Invalid image height.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[gif @ 0x5613f540edc0] Invalid image height.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[gif @ 0x5613f540edc0] Invalid image height.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[gif @ 0x5613f540edc0] Invalid image height.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[gif @ 0x5613f540edc0] Invalid image height.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[gif @ 0x5613f540edc0] Invalid image height.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[gif @ 0x5613f540edc0] Invalid image height.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[gif @ 0x5613f540edc0] Invalid image height.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[gif @ 0x5613f540edc0] Invalid image height.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[gif @ 0x5613f540edc0] Invalid image height.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[gif @ 0x5613f540edc0] Invalid image height.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp4 @ 0x5613f541f380] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=23.0 Lsize=       3kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=253795.9kbits/s speed=0.0245x    
video:2kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 34.588745%
[libx264 @ 0x5613f5420c80] frame I:1     Avg QP:21.16  size:  1622
[libx264 @ 0x5613f5420c80] mb I  I16..4: 14.3% 42.9% 42.9%
[libx264 @ 0x5613f5420c80] 8x8 transform intra:42.9%
[libx264 @ 0x5613f5420c80] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 67.9% 41.1% 33.9%
[libx264 @ 0x5613f5420c80] i16 v,h,dc,p: 25% 38% 25% 12%
[libx264 @ 0x5613f5420c80] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  8% 58% 18%  2%  3%  3%  1%  4%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x5613f5420c80] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 29% 15%  7%  7%  6%  5%  4%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x5613f5420c80] i8c dc,h,v,p: 77%  5% 16%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x5613f5420c80] kb/s:64.88
Conversion failed!
```

I'm a newbie with ffmpeg, but as far as I understand, the `-vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2"` scales the image so that it height and width are even numbers (needed for mp4 file format), so that should prevent this sort of error from occurring?

This looks very similar to [this issue](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6874) over at trac.ffmpeg.org, which has apparently been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that even though it was fixed a while ago, the fix only landed in version `4.2`. There are several options to install a more recent version: use a PPA, download `ffmpeg`, or compile it.

## PPAs

To install version 4.2 on Ubuntu **19.04**, I followed [these steps](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/08/install-ffmpeg-4-2-ubuntu-18-04/):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/ffmpeg4
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/graphics
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/multimedia
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

And now it handles the GIF fine. For Ubuntu **18.04**, [this](https://www.osradar.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-18-04/) worked for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-4
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

## Download a compiled ffmpeg

Alternatively you can [download `ffmpeg`](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) that has already been compiled. Place it in `~/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` if you want it in your `PATH` ([more info on installation](https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/faq/)).

## Compile ffmpeg

Or you can follow a step-by-step guide to [compile `ffmpeg` on Ubuntu](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).